# Processing "Join by attribute" issue

Tags: qgis-processing, attribute-joins

I don't know what's going wrong when I try to join a shapefile with an .xls or CSV. I do have the same identifier in both files. The joined file has all the expected columns but they are all empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are they the same type? That is are they both text, for example? Or is one a number and the other text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure the identifier field in both files are the same type. That is make sure they're both text or both numeric.

Comment: Thanx! I got it.